# Rails scope for the current tenant

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a multi tenant Rails app.

I use this line of code in each of the models:

```
default_scope { where(tenant_id: Tenant.current_id) }
```

I have a model called `worequest` and it contains an integer column called `request_closed`.  I would like each tenant to define which `statuscode` is closed for them.

After the `default_scope` statement, I'm trying to set a scope for requests that are not closed.

I've tried the following and they don't work:

```
scope :closed, where(:statuscode_id => Tenant.current.request_closed)
scope :closed, where(:statuscode_id => current_tenant.request_closed)
scope :closed, where(:statuscode_id => Tenant.request_closed)
scope :closed, where(:statuscode_id => Tenant.current_id.request_closed)
```

Is it possible to do what I want?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what is `worequest` and how does it relate to `Tenant`?

Comment: tenant_id is a column(field) in every model(table).  The multi-tenancy is based on the prefix to the url.  For instance, ame.ndeavor.dev will match the "ame" to the tenants model.  The idea is from railscast EPISODE #388.

Comment: I understand that. You're trying to access `request_closed` from somewhere, I'm trying to determine where `request_closed` is stored. You said it is stored on a `worequest` model but you then said nothing else about it.

Comment: `request_closed` is a column(field) in the model(table) `tenants`.

Comment: Then `Tenant.find(Tenant.current_id).request_closed` will probably do it.

Comment: Thanks Mike !! If you create an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as `request_closed` is an attribute on `Tenant`, you'll need to retrieve your current tenant, using your `current_id` value, and then call it on that.

```
Tenant.find(Tenant.current_id).request_closed
```